# how can you subset last values of a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that sorta looks like this in its basic form...

```
subject session 
1         1
2         1
3         1
1         2
2         2
3         2
1         3
2         3
3         3
1         4
2         4
3         4
1         5
2         5
3         5
```

How can I subset just the last 2 sessions of the data frame (i.e. sessions 4 and 5)?

Note: The total number of sessions may change between scenarios but I will always only want to look at the last 2 sessions.

So code like this would not suffice all scenarios...

```
data <- subset(data, session == c(4,5))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With more than one element, use `%in%` instead of `==`.  Get the `unique` 'session' values and return the last two with `tail`, create the logical expression with `%in%` for subsetting

```
subset(data, session %in% tail(unique(session), 2))
```

As @Greg mentioned in the comments, if it should be based on the ordered 'session' and the column values are not sorted, the do the `sort` on the `unique` elements before applying the `tail`

```
subset(data, session %in% tail(sort(unique(session)), 2))
```

Comment: I think OP wants something that will always select the final 2 sessions (or more generally the final `n` sessions), regardless of how many distinct sessions there are.

Comment: Maybe use `sort()` too, optionally, just in case OP wants the final two sessions _by number_ rather than by order of appearance.

Comment: Thank you! akrun's answer worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option

```
> subset(df, session >= sort(unique(session), decreasing = TRUE)[2])
   subject session
10       1       4
11       2       4
12       3       4
13       1       5
14       2       5
15       3       5
```

or

```
> subset(df, session >= -sort(-unique(session))[2])
   subject session
10       1       4
11       2       4
12       3       4
13       1       5
14       2       5
15       3       5
```